# Factoring out a Cohen forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose that in a forcing extension $V[G]$ by some ccc forcing $P$ there is a Cohen real over $V$. By a general argument we can factor $P$ into an iteration $P=\mathrm{Add}(\omega,1)*\dot{Q}$ for some ccc quotient forcing $\dot{Q}$. Can we do better and factor $P$ as a *product* $\mathrm{Add}(\omega,1)\times R$ for some forcing $R$? Is every extension containing a Cohen real a Cohen extension of some intermediate model?

Comment: Have you tried to consider a case where $\dot Q$ is something like $\rm Add(\omega_1,1)$? It seems to me that you could have encoded the generic Cohen into such $R$ if it existed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good point. I think that might be a problem, but in the case I have in mind $P$ (and therefore $\dot{Q}$) is ccc. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you first add a Cohen real and then, over the resulting model, force Martin's axiom and not CH in the usual way (by a ccc, finite-support iteration).  The resulting model has no Souslin trees, because MA$(\aleph_1)$ implies Souslin's hypothesis.  So this model is not of the form "add a Cohen real to some model", because adding a Cohen real always produces a Souslin tree.

Comment: Thank you. Now why didn't I think of that? :)